# Planning Description Configuration Wizard not launching

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the process of doing the Planning Description Configuration Wizard tutorial I am running

roslaunch planning_environment planning_description_configuration_wizard.launch urdf_package:=planning_models urdf_path:=test_urdf/robot.xml

as per the instructions. However, I recieve the error:

/opt/ros/electric/stacks/arm_navigation/planning_environment/bin/planning_description_configuration_wizard: error while loading shared libraries: libvtkIO.so.5.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[planning_description_configuration_wizard-3] process has died [pid 12506, exit code 127].
log files: /home/robbie/.ros/log/742288a6-0cb4-11e1-a787-001ec936b097/planning_description_configuration_wizard-3*.log

I am running ROS Electric on Ubuntu 11.10. I have tried copying the libvtk 5.6 library files in /usr/lib to have the 5.4 extension, but this results in a symbol not found error. I also tried downloading the source for VTK 5.4, compiling it with shared libraries enabled, and copying the creating library files into /usr/lib, but this also resulted in an error.

I am new to ROS, so any help would be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11911/planning-description-configuration-wizard-not-launching/) by [robbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1365/robbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2011-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2011-11-17**:
That version of libvtk is the one from natty - did you install 11.04 debs on an 11.10 system?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-17**:
Please post your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and how you have installed all packages.  Also helpful would be an ldd of planning_description_configuration_wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I did not update `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` after upgrading. It appears to work now. Thank you for the help.

---

Originally posted by [robbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1365/robbie/) with karma: 20 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0